# how to pay for windows 10 dev environment

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

According to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/ the Windows 10 Enterprise VM "will expire on 5/10/20". My question is...  can I pay to make this version *not* expire?

I could buy Windows 10 Pro from [https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Windows-10-Pro-Download/dp/B01019BOEA/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=windows+10&qid=1582776174&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01019BOEA) for ~$200 but (1) that'd be a fresh install and (2) it wouldn't be setup in the same way that the Windows 10 Enterprise VM was. Windows Subsystem for Linux wouldn't be pre-installed, Visual Studio 2019 wouldn't be pre-installed, etc.

Comment: Only a Windows 10 Enterprise license can activate a Windows 10 Enterprise installation.  Purchasing Windows 10 Professional wouldn’t be productive.  *Those developer VMs cannot be activated*. Visual Studio typically isn’t a free product, certain versions are free, but I got a feeling that isn’t what’s installed.  It’s also trivial to install Visual Studio